# Deleting a value from an array in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to do something like this:

Say at first iteration I have

```
  A={2,3,5}
```

and then in the second iteration it becomes

```
  A={2,3}
```

and so on. I tried making the third element zero after my first iteration but then the algorithm is going wrong.

What is the way in C++ to delete an element in an array as we perform each iteration?

Comment: Why don't you use a `vector`?

Comment: For the best answer, we need to know what your algorithm does.

Comment: What is an array? If it is the values between 2 pointers `first` and `end`, then removing the last element is just `--end`.

Comment: It is a circuit partitioning algorithm. No the value which is being deleted is not always at the back. How is vector useful? Or do we need to use linked lists? Pl.s let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best (and most C++ - like) approach is to switch from an array to a resizable container, such as [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). This container is resized dynamically, letting you delete elements from the end or from any other place in the container. The container would then resize to the correct size.

```
// Create a vector
std::vector<int> mydata(10, -1);
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++)
    mydata[i] = i;
// Process all elements
for (int i = 0 ; i != mydata.size() ; i++) {
    cout << mydata[i] << endl;
}
// Remove the last element
mydata.pop_back();
// Process all elements - now the last one is not there
for (int i = 0 ; i != mydata.size() ; i++) {
    cout << mydata[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/48KkE1).

Comment: deque may be better if removing many elements but +1 good answer.

Comment: `mydata.erase(mydata.end()-1)` is verbose. Why not use `mydata.pop_back()`?

Comment: @Rapptz You're right, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete elements in regular array in C++. If you are using List or vector then it is other thing, but with plain arrays you can only create new array, and copy values from old array without value which you want to "delete". And then say "new array" is "old array".

Answer (score 0):

For C++ style: use std:vector and following that [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).
For C style: use dynamic heap arrays i.e. new/delete/realloc

Answer (score 0):

Picture an array as metal structure with slots.  The slots cannot be changed, they are fixed.

Fill the slots with books. This is like putting values in an array.

Remove the 3rd book from the 3rd slot.  Because it is a metal structure with fixed slots, none of the other books are adjusted or moved.  They are in their original positions.

To "remove" the empty slot, pull a book from the next slot and place into the empty slot.  Repeat until the "empty" slot is at the end or all the remaining books have been moved. This is how a `std::vector` will remove an item.

A linked list is more efficient at removing slots.  Think of a linked list as a bunch of containers that have a hook one one end and as string on the other.  You can tie the string only to one container's hook.  Following the string gives you the order of the containers.  To remove a container, untie the previous container's string and tie it to the hook of the next container, then untie the container's string.  You didn't have to copy or move any of the remaining elements; you just moved the string.

Unless you keep track of the removed container, it may get lost.  This situation is called a memory leak:  a lost item in memory.